# $routeProvider , Clicking same link more than once

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Below is my partial angularJS code which implements routeprovider

```
   TicketApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    // route for Create Ticket Page
    .when('/CreateTicket', {
        templateUrl: '../Ticket/Create',
        controller: 'CreateCtrl'
    })

    // route for Open Ticket Page
    .when('/OpenTickets', {
        templateUrl: '../Ticket/MyTickets',
        controller: 'MyTicketsCtrl'
    })

     // route for All Users Search Page
    .when('/SearchUsers', {
        templateUrl: '../Account/AllUsers',
        controller: 'AllUsersCtrl'
    })
..........
```

When user clicks SAME link more than once, only the 
first click makes an AJAX request ,the subsequent requests
do not.

What needs to be modified so that subsequent requests to SAME link also make an AJAX call.

EDIT :

I also added below code

```
TicketApp.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache, $location) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

$templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl); 

});
});
```

did not work for me.. :(

Comment: The current route doesn't reload on link click

Answer (score 0):

Why do want to execute Ajax requests? It is only one request required to load the **template** from the server. There is no need to load it multiple time, because it shouldn't change or your architecture is not really compliant to Angular.

You could probably invalidate the *templateCache* and force Angular to reload the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will work for your case .When the user will click the Button(the ajax call start's) you just hide it(button) once the AJAX call return a response back then show it(button).